# Embedding Dimension of a graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, let the embedding dimension of a graph be the least number $n$ such that there exists a partitioning of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the contact graph is $G$. **Is there any way to bound the embedding dimension?**

Suppose a graph is the cartesian product $G \times H$. **Is there any way to bound the embedding dimension of the product given the embedding dimensions of $G$ and $H$.**

Comment: For the contact graph, do you consider two sets to be in contact when they touch along a single point in $\mathbb R^2$? or along a 1-dimensional curve in $\mathbb R^3$? (Also, you have not said it, but I assume that the parts in the partition of $\mathbb R^n$ must be connected, or else the question becomes trivial.)

Comment: It has to be an n-1 cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any connected graph has embedding dimension at most $3$. (Only planar graphs can have embedding dimension $2$, and disconnected graphs aren't the contact graphs of any partition of $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$, so this describes all embedding dimensions.)

We can begin by taking a spanning tree of $G$, and drawing it as the contact graph of a partition of $\mathbb R^2$, such as in the picture below:

[image]

We can think of this as sitting in $\mathbb R^3$, just by repeating this picture indefinitely in the third dimension.

Next, we can add any edge to this spanning tree by adding a narrow tube connecting the regions, and pinching together the regions in between:

[image]

In this 2D picture, this makes the in-between regions look disconnected, but since this only happens in a small range of $z$-values, they're still connected elsewhere.

We can do this any number of times (at different "heights" in the third dimension) to add in all the edges we need to build $G$.